# SQL Server/SSRS is using case to build where a clause feasible?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

What I'm doing seems like it should be an SSRS/SQL trope with best practices, but I spent the better part of yesterday trying to google and test this with no luck:

I have two parameters: param_date and param_partno, that are used to query a table of invoices and related invoices. I need it to filter based on one parameter, the other, or a combination of both (anded). I've done this a million of times, but apparently not ever with a date/time field directly in SQL. I'm looking to avoid using a null value, because I'm nont sure the end audience will get the checkbox

In pseudo-code:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    invoices
where
    case(
        if (@param_date > 0) and (param_partno > 0) then + 
            " param_date=@param_date and param_partno = @param_partno"
        if (@param_date > 0) then + 
            " param_date=@param_date"
        if (param_partno > 0) then + 
            " param_partno = @param_partno"
    )
```

Stupid simple to do in a programming or scripting language, But doing it directly in an SQL Server/SSRS context is kicking my buttox.

Thanks for your consideration!

JimB

PS: these reports is only available on our company's intranet.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you? Next time please add some scripts for testdata.

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices
WHERE (
          @param_date > 0
          AND param_partno > 0
          AND param_date = @param_date
          AND param_partno = @param_partno
      )
      OR
      (
          @param_date > 0
          AND param_date = @param_date
          AND param_partno = 0
      )
      OR
      (
          param_partno > 0
          AND param_partno = @param_partno
          AND @param_date = 0
      );
```

Comment: I had something like, though not as mature, this but was having issues with SSRS not allowing a date parameter be blank. Seeing this, I'm thinking if I set @param_date as text, but test is for correct date form in SSRS and cast it as a date/time on the SQL end, this may work... let's see...

Comment: You can make your parameter nullable, then, I thought a checkbox also was added to say empty.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that because my customers may not get the concept, total, non-tech

Comment: Your suggestion works for the second two cases, when you have values for both parameters, it trips all three OR's and gives you the both sets instead of a smaller set. That's what sent me down the CASE path, because it will only execute the first matching test.

Comment: You might want to expand the second and third part to exclude the ones which must be true in the other one.

Comment: Ive done that change in my answer now. Will that work better for you?

Comment: Got It! You Rock!

Answer (score 1):

This works, with much help from @pete! Now, I just have to test for a properly formed date on the front end. I'd still be open to anyone with better or best practices

```
declare @param_date as varchar(32)
declare @param_partno as varchar(32)
SET @param_date = ''
SET @param_partno='Z03020112142'

select 
    * 
from 
    flagsreceived
WHERE (
          len(@param_date) > 0
          AND len(@param_partno) > 0
          AND DATERECD = @param_date
          AND itemnmbr = @param_partno
      )
      OR
      (
          len(@param_date) > 0
          and len(@param_partno) = 0
          AND DATERECD = @param_date
      )
      OR
      (
          len(@param_partno) > 0
           and len(@param_date) = 0
          AND itemnmbr = @param_partno
      );
```

Comment: UGH! The query works in SSMS, but returns nothing in SSRS's query builder! I don't understand! --EDIT: NM, rookie mistake, I forgot to switch the default empty value to blank instead of null *blush*